# jquery check if option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-selectors

I am having a situation where i need to see if an option is selected or not.When i click a button,  if an option is not selected, the select box should turn red and give me an alert. It does not work. I am having difficaulty with the if statement. Any solution?

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $films = [];

$("#button").click(function(){
    var $titelBetyg = [];

    var $titel = $('#name').val();
    var $betyg = $('#options').val();

    if($titel == ""){
        $('#name').css('background-color', 'red');
        alert("Fail");
    }
    else if($betyg == "0"){
        $('#options').css('background-color', 'red');
        alert("Fail");
    }
    else{
        $titelBetyg.push($titel);
        $titelBetyg.push($betyg);
        $films.push($titelBetyg);
    }

    $('#rightbar').append($films);
});

});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <h1> Min filminsamling </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Lägg till en film:</legend>
                Titel:
                <br><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
                Betyg:
                <br><select id="options">
                    <option>Välj betyg här...</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>                        
                </select>
                <br><input type="button" name="button" value="Spara film" id="button">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sortera film:</legend>
                <input type="button" name="stigande" value="Högst betyg" id="stigande">
                <br><input type="button" name="fallande" value="Lägst betyg" id="fallande">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbar">
        Filmer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: depending on the browser, you will actually have "Välj betyg här..." as your default value and not "" as you would expect. chrome is a culprit of this as well as others

Comment: If no option is marked as selected, one option is always selected (unless you are using option groups I think). From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.1): *"Since user agent behavior differs, authors should ensure that each menu includes a default pre-selected OPTION."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$betyg == "0"` isn't working because it isn't a possibility according to the UI.

Your default option is... nothing. Perhaps an empty string, `""`; nowhere does `0` appear.

Explicitly set an option to check for, and check for it.

Comment: Ya, similar to what Grant is saying.  If you just change your like of code to `else if(!$betyg){`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you check whether to warn that nothing is selected, you look to see if the value of "option" is "0".  Yet you didn't actually define the value of "0" for no selection, you only defined values "1" through "5".  I'm not sure what to expect with Javascript if you ask for the value of something whose value is undefined; my first suggestion would be to define the value "0" for no selection and see if it helps.  :)